# Should dict store key in order by inc?

Tags: python

I have a dict with integers as keys. Tell me please, does a dict store data with sorted keys or not?

I wrote a little code to test (as follows):

```
>>> 
>>> d = {1: 'a', 3: 'a'}
>>> d
{1: 'a', 3: 'a'}
>>> d[2] = 'a'
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a'}
>>>
```

But I am not sure that this behavior is standard and works all the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Element order in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792190/python-element-order-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries in python are not sorted. Read more on dicts here:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict

But you can use [sorted python built-in method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=any#sorted) to sort keys:

```
for k in sorted(myDict):
    myDict[k] # do something
```

Or Look here for [collections.OrderedDict implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict)

You can also mix sorted method and OrderedDict to use it later(sure this will only word in case you will not add new items into it - otherwise it simply better to use sorted method):

```
d = {1: 'a', 3: 'a'}   
from collections import OrderedDict   
sorted_d = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d))
```

Comment: just to note that all an `OrderedDict` does is keeping track of the *order that keys are inserted*. Very different from keeping keys *sorted*.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit more experimenting would have soon shown you that they are not sorted:

```
>>> d = {1: 'a', 3: 'a', 8: 'a'}
>>> d
{8: 'a', 1: 'a', 3: 'a'}
```

but even that is implementation dependant. Don't depend on the order at all.

Answer (score 1):

The internal dict keeps no sorting order for the keys. If you want a fast C-implementation for C python have a look at sorteddict which is included in my ordereddict package for CPython:
http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/Python/ordereddict/

Comment: Anyone know of pure python implementation of the sorteddict?