# How to iterate over nested dictionaries in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm not sure the most efficient way to iterate over my nested dictionaries to print a matrix of the total and good values for every fruit for each date.  Take for instance the two lists and dictionary below:

```
fruits = ['apples','oranges','bananas']
harvest_dates = ['2011-07-23','2011-07-22','2011-07-21']

harvest_data = {
  'apples': {
    '2011-07-23': {
      'total': 100,
      'good': 80},
     '2011-07-22': {
       'total': 97,
       'good': 92},
     '2011-07-21': {
       'total': 90,
       'good': 85}
  },
  'oranges': {
    '2011-07-23': {
      'total': 86,
      'good': 82},
    '2011-07-22': {
      'total': 90, 
      'good': 75},
    '2011-07-21': {
      'total': 92,
      'good': 92}
  },
  'bananas': {
    '2011-07-23': {
      'total': 10,
      'good': 9},
    '2011-07-22': {
      'total': 12, 
      'good': 11},
    '2011-07-21': {
      'total': 9,
      'good': 9}
  }
}
```

I can easily do this in python:

```
for fruit in fruits:
  for day in harvest_dates:
    print "harvest: %s" % harvest_data[fruit][day]['total']
    print "good crop: %s" % harvest_data[fruit][day]['good']
```

But I don't know how to access this data in django templates.  I had been trying something such as:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
  ...
  {% for day in harvest_dates %}
    ...
    {{ harvest_data.fruit.day.total }}
    {{ harvest_data.fruit.day.good }}
    ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it's simply not working.

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
  {{ harvest_data.fruit }}  <--- this does not exist
  {{ harvest_data[fruit] }}  <--- this does not work
{% endfor %}
```

I'm a complete amateur and I'm probably going about this all wrong, but I've Google'd quite a bit and it's not clear to me what the best approach to getting the data I want is.

Answer (score 41):

Since you're familiar with python, the following is logically how you would want to iterate through your dictionary in a Django template:

```
for key,value in harvest_data.items():
...     print key
...     for key2,value2 in value.items():
...         print key2
...         for key3,value3 in value2.items():
...             print "%s:%s"%(key3,value3)
```

In your template, this translates as follows:

```
{% for key, value in harvest_data.items %}
    {{ key }} <br>
    {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        {{ key2 }} <br>
        {% for key3, value3 in value2.items %}
            {{ key3 }}:{{ value3 }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The Django docs actually briefly include an example of how to iterate through dictionaries when describing how the `for` template tag works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense, but I guess the problem I'm finding is that I need to grab a specific value from one of the nested dictionaries based on where I'm at in looping through the fruits and dates.  If I simply loop through the harvest_data as you mention, is it guaranteed that all my dates will line up?

Comment: i think you'd be better off looping through a dictionary than trying to grab specific values from a separate dictionary in your template. Standard dictionaries in python have no order, but if you wanted to preserve the order you could use a sorted dictionary (see this SO answer for more on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792190/python-element-order-in-dictionary).

Comment: updated my answer to include different keywords for each iteration per @Hassek's comment below.

Answer (score 8):

as rolling stone says thats the way to iterate over dictionaries in templates, i would only change the key, value keywords for different keywords in every iteration like this:

```
{% for key, value in harvest_data.items %}
    {{ key }} <br>
    {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        {{ key2 }} <br>
        {% for key3, value3 in value2.items %}
            {{ key3 }}:{{ value3 }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

just for the sake of clarity :)

And if you want to line up your values i would suggest you use another data structure where you can sort by date, for example a something like this:

```
{ 'oranges' : [(date1, value1), (date2,value2)] ...}
```

Try to do the least possible operations in your templates, so dont do a sort or nested if's if you dont have to

Comment: thanks @Hassek, updated my answer to include different key, value keywords. btw you've got a small typo in your update, `{{ key3 }}:{{ value }}` should be `{{ key3 }}:{{ value3 }} `

Answer (score 1):

Really old question, but I will add my 1.5c.

This is a good use case of the regroup tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) and a bit of data refactoring:

1. Have your data as a simple list of data points:

   ```
   harvest_data = [
       {'fruits': 'apples', 'date': '2011-07-23', 'total': 100, 'good': 80},
       # ...
   ]
   ```
2. In your template, group by the chosen dimension(s):

   ```
   {% regroup harvest_data by fruits as data_by_fruits %}
   {% for data in data_by_fruits %}
       <h1>{{ data.grouper }}</h1>   # 'apples'
       {% regroup data.list by date as data_by_fruits_date %}
       {% for data_1 in data_by_fruits_date %}
           <h2>{{ data_1.grouper }}</h2>    # '2011-07-23'
           {% for datapoint in data_1.list %}
               total: {{ datapoint.total }} <br/>
               good: {{ datapoint.good }} <br/>
           {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```