# Iterate through nested dict in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I found some solutions to iterate through dict in django templates (such as [How to iterate over nested dictionaries in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates)) but it's always for a defined depth.

For instance, if I have this dict :

```
{'a':{'b':'c',
      'd':'e',
      'f':'g',
      'h':{'i':'j',
           'k':'l',
           'm':'n'
          }
      }
  'o':'p'
}
```

But I can also have :

```
{'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':'e',
                'f':'g'
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

Is there another way than the recursive one to do this ? If not, is it possible to do recursion in django templates ? 
The only way to do this I think is to create custom filters such as `get_sons` and `has_son` and work with it. Is it the good way to do this ?

**Additional informations :**

I have the structure stored in a model such as :

```
class XMLStructure(Model.models):
    node_name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('XMLStructure')

    @staticmethod
    def get_root(self):
        # return the root of the structure

    def has_children(self):
        # return true / false if it's a leaf

    @staticmethod 
    def get_leaves(self): 
        # return all leaves of my xml
```

and a function `build` who generate the xml structure as a dict.

I tried to use code from Django Snippets but I cannot make them work (Always got an `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`)

I though it would be easier to transform my dict into a list. My first dict would be :

```
dict_as_list = ['a','/','b','d','f','h','/','i','k','m','\','\','o','\']
```

and then store the values into a dict. As you can see, I'm pretty desperate.

Thanks

Comment: There is no much info on how your dict is generated or where it comes from, there are different approaches you could take, one would be to add a model method to iterate through them, another would be to create a template tag or filter, a view helper is also another possible solution.

Comment: I edited my post in order to give more informations

Comment: Recursion is possible in Django templates, although I wouldn't use it since it dramatically decreases readability of the template.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no choice, it's an xml path that I have to render in the view. This one can be parameterized with an admin interface so the depth can vary... 

But I agree with you, I saw some examples and it's not elegant.

I still wonder how people manage to render nested dict in a view ...