# how to get family tree using Django template and from ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django

I need family tree, I'm not using any library here( can you suggest ). First can you look into my model first so you will come to know the idea.

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    familyname = models.ForeignKey(FamilyName)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='p', symmetrical=False)
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='c', symmetrical=False)
```

And my view function look like

```
def explore_home(request):
    old_date = FamilyMember.objects.filter(familyname__name = family_name).aggregate(Min('birth_date'))
    member_obj_all = FamilyMember.objects.get(familyname__name = family_name, birth_date=old_date['birth_date__min'])
```

And I am using `this code` for build the family tree.

In my django template I do like

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">{{ family_name }}</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">{{ member_obj_all }}</a>
                    {% if member_obj_all.children.all %}

                    <!-- here we go again -->
                        <ul>
                            {% for child_obj in member_obj_all.children.all %}
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">{{ child_obj }}</a>

                                    {% if child_obj.children.all %}
                                    <!-- here we go againg -->
                                    <ul>
                                        {% for grand_child_obj in child_obj.children.all %}
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="">{{ grand_child_obj }}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                    {% endif %}

                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ok above code working and the output is like ...

[image]

But what if i have n number of children and then children's children and How to automate the process again.? (in template ? ). See i just have this idea and if you have any idea then please tell me here.

Comment: You could use a recursive function that keeps calling itself (the "here we go again" part of your template), you should obviously have the recursive function in your view, and you should return a dictionary with all the nested levels as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this *(not tested)*:

```
//child.html
<a href="#">{{child}}</a>
{% if child.children.count %}
    <ul>
        {% for child_obj in child.children.all %}
        <li>
            {% include 'child.html' with child=child_obj %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}


//tree.html
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">{{ family_name }}</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">{{ member_obj_all }}</a>
                    {% if member_obj_all.children.count %}
                        <ul>
                            {% for child_obj in member_obj_all.children.all %}
                            <li>
                                {% include 'child.html' with child=child_obj %}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Try to replace `{% if child.children.all %}` with `count` - `{% if child.children.count %}`. However you should get the idea, having a template rendering a child and for each child of the child the template include itself.

Comment: Can you inspect your data? Is there any chance to have a child with his parent as a child, e.g. `FamilyMember A` have children `[FamilyMember B, FamilyMember C]` and `FamilyMember B` have children `[FamilyMember D, FamilyMember A]` this can cause and infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks buddy... Some of my data mishandled.. I fixed that now it's working magicly .. You save my day .. thanks ..