# Printing nested dictionary values that may or may not exist

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in Python (Django), like so:

```
books = 
 { 
   1: { 1: 'Alice', 2: 'Bob', 3: 'Marta' }, 
   2: { 1: 'Alice', 3: 'Marta' }, 
   3: { 1: 'Alice', 2: 'Bob' }, 
 }
```

Now in my template I want to print a particular item, but only if it exists, for instance books[4][1]. But if I do this, I get:

```
{{ books[4][1] }}

Error: Could not parse the remainder
```

So I do a check:

```
{% if 4 in books %}
  {% if 1 in books[4] %}
     {{ books[4][1] %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This also doesn't work and gives a parse error (Could not parse the remainder). What is the proper way to print a nested dictionary value in Django if I"m not sure if it exists in the dictionary?

Comment: check this example if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django template language is *deliberately* different from Python code, such that people are discouraged to write business logic into it.

But the template logic is strong enough to perform an item-getter on the items, by writing this in dot notation. For example:

```
{{ books[4][1] }}
```

Should be written like:

```
{{ books.4.1 }}
```

So you can write it like:

```
{% if 4 in books %}
  {% if 1 in books.4 %}
     {{ books.4.1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

That being said, all these lookups are not necessary at all. Since Django typically will *not* produce an error if a lookup fails. In that case, it will fallback to the `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` string when it needs to print it. Which is by default empty, so we could avoid the trouble and write:

```
{{ books.4.1 }}
```

which will, in case the element does *not* exists, print the `settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` (if not specified, it is the empty string).

In case you want to perform a check, you *can* use an `if` directly on the entire variable, like:

```
{% if books.4.1 %}
  {{ books.4.1 %}
{% endif %}
```

to check if this "template variable" expressions gets resolved, and the result has *truthiness* `True`.

Comment: Also, instead of individual `if` statements you can use `{% if books.4.1 %}` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Cole: or simply a `default` filter, since in case it does not get resolved, it will perform that fallback anyway.

Comment: True, unless there is additional html between the if/endif that is probably the best implementation

Comment: Great! This is very nice to know. It solves this specific question, although in fact I don't have keys (4, 1) for the indexes but have variables, so I'm now running into another problem. But let me post that separately, this answers the question as asked. Thanks.