# Django template syntax for nested dictionary item using variable names

Tags: python, django, dictionary

On a Django template page, I'm trying to access the value inside a nested dictionary.

```
books = 
 { 
   1: { 1: 'Alice', 2: 'Bob', 3: 'Marta' }, 
   2: { 1: 'Alice', 3: 'Marta' }, 
   3: { 1: 'Alice', 2: 'Bob' }, 
 }
```

Somewhere on my page, I have these two variables

```
info.id = 1
detail.id = 2
```

What I want to do is print (if it exists) the item `books[1][2]`, or in other words `books[info.id][detail.id]`. I ran into trouble because I couldn't access this nested variable. This got [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124186/printing-nested-dictionary-values-that-may-or-may-not-exist). However, the solution proposed was to access nested dictionary items using the dot notation. But the problem is that this doesn't seem to work when using variables. Using that logic, I would do:

```
{{ books.info.id.detail.id }}
```

But this doesn't yield any result. How should I approach the situation when using variables to access the items in a dictionary? Do note that the actual item may or may not exist, which is why I run into trouble using `books[info.id][detail.id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the template directly. You'll need to use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/). This would work:

```
@register.simple_tag
def nested_get(dct, key1, key2):
    return dct.get(key1, {}).get(key2)
```

Now you can use it in the template:

```
{% load my_tags_library %}
{% nested_get books item.id detail.id %}
```

Comment: Yes yes yes!! Thanks a lot, this solved my issue, been struggling with this for hours.