# nested dictionaries in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

In python,

```
        data = {
        {0 : {kill : 1}},
        {1 : {kill : 3}},
        {2 : {kill : 8}}
       }
       for i in data:
        print(data[i]['kill'])
```

print 1,3,8 nomarlly

but in Django template

```
    {% for i in data %}
    {{ data.i.kill }}
```

It's making error.

However, using an integer instead of variable i will operate normally.
like

```
{{ data.0.kill}}
```

I found solution in 
[How to iterate over nested dictionaries in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates)

but it have to use double for loop.
is there solution to solve without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested dictionaries are going to produce an error. I am going to assume that data is meant to be the following:

```
data = {
  0 : {kill : 1},
  1 : {kill : 3},
  2 : {kill : 8}
}
```

In which case you can do the following to print 1 3 8

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ value.kill }}
{% endfor %}
```