# Looping through nested dicts in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, nested-loops

I have a nested dict that I am passing as context to a template of the following structure:

```
cWeeks{
    1: {
           'receivables': { 'customer': 'x', 'amount': 'y', ...}
           'payables': { 'customer': 'x', 'amount': 'y', ...}
       }
    2: {
           etc
       }
}
```

In my template I have a for loop iterating over each number and then another nested for loop that should iterate over all items in 'receivables'. Unfortunately that second loop never begins.

This is the relevant code in the template:

```
{% for cw in cWeeks %}
            <div class="kw1">
                <div class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header text-center">KW {{ cw }}</h5>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        {% for receivable in cw.receivables %}
                        <li class="list-group-item zahlung payment-receivable">
                            <div class="payment-content">
                                <div class="typ">Zahlung</div>
                                <div class="kunde">{{ receivable.customer }}</div>
                                <div class="kwSelektor">
                                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                                        <div class="form-group formKwSelektor">
                                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="kwxxSelektor">
                                                <option value="10">KW 10</option>
                                                <option value="11">KW 11</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">KW ändern</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="betrag">{{ receivable.amount }}</div>
                                <div class="bank">{{ receivable.account }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *

def home(request):
    """ Calendar Weeks payments overview """
    cWeeks = {1: dict(), 2: dict(), 3: dict(), 4: dict()}
    for week in range(1, 5):
        cWeeks[week]['receivables'] = Receivable.objects.all()
        cWeeks[week]['payables'] = Payable.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cwView.html', {'cWeeks': cWeeks})
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over nested dictionaries in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately not entirely. My problem is that I want to iterate over the precise sub_dict "receivables" and I do not understand how to specifically call that in the template language. Basically a similar problem the author of the question you linked is asking in the comments to the first answer.