# Django - Queryset results not displaying in template

Tags: python, django, templates, view, django-queryset

I am learning Django and building an inventory app for a laboratory. I already have data in all my models, and now I want to search the database based on some criteria and display the results in a table.
First I ask the user to input the search terms (that part works), then I query the db (that also works) but when it's time to display results all I get is an empty template. No error messages.

**These are my views:**

```
def choose_filter_primers(request):   # this works fine
    if request.method == "GET":
        radiobtn_form = PrimerRadiobtn(request.GET)
        
        if radiobtn_form.is_valid():
            # get value from user input and store it in request.session dict
            request.session['filter_by'] = radiobtn_form.cleaned_data['CHOOSE_FIELD']
            # go to the next step in the search form
            return render(request, 'lab_inventory/filter_primers.html')
    else:
        radiobtn_form = PrimerRadiobtn()
    
    return render(request, 'lab_inventory/choose_filter_primers.html', {'radiobtn_form': radiobtn_form})


def filter_primers(request):    # this works fine
    # get filter field from views.choose_filter_primers
    filter_by = request.session.get('filter_by')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FilterPrimerForm(request.POST)# or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # get value from user input and store it in request.session dict
            request.session['contains'] = form.cleaned_data.get("contains")           
            # go to the next step in the search form
            return render(request, 'lab_inventory/search_results_primers.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'lab_inventory/choose_filter_primers.html')
    else:
        form = FilterPrimerForm(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
        
    return render(request, 'lab_inventory/filter_primers.html', context)


def search_results_primers(request):   # MY PROBLEM IS HERE SOMEWHERE
    search_term = request.GET['contains'] # this variable refers to the value 'Ha'
    filter_by = request.session.get('filter_by') # this variable refers to the value 'primer_name'

    if filter_by == 'primer_name':
        query = Primer.objects.filter(primer_name__contains=search_term).values()
        result = {'query': query}
        
        return render(request, 'lab_inventory/search_results_primers.html', result)
```

The query in `search_results_primers` returns this (from running it in the shell):

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 303, 'primer_name': 'Ha-9-F', 'primer_seq': '5-TAGCTAACTTGGCCTGAAGCCTC-3', 'purchase_order': 201, 'date_received': datetime.date(2001, 1, 16), 'date_opened': datetime.date(2001, 1, 30), 'date_discarded': datetime.date(2001, 2, 27), 'stored_freezer': '-20/3', 'stored_box': 'H / 2'},
 {'id': 304, 'primer_name': 'Ha-9-R', 'primer_seq': '5-TCTCCCTCCGAAGCAGGTTTCGCGG-3', 'purchase_order': 201, 'date_received': datetime.date(2001, 1, 16), 'date_opened': datetime.date(2001, 1, 30), 'date_discarded': datetime.date(2001, 2, 27), 'stored_freezer': '-20/3', 'stored_box': 'H / 3'},
 {'id': 311, 'primer_name': 'Ha-10-F', 'primer_seq': '5-GTCCTGAATCATGTTTCCCCTGCAC-3', 'purchase_order': 205, 'date_received': datetime.date(2003, 12, 19), 'date_opened': datetime.date(2004, 1, 2), 'date_discarded': datetime.date(2004, 1, 30), 'stored_freezer': '-20/1', 'stored_box': 'F / 7'},]  '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

and that is correct, *it is the search result that I want*, so far so good. But then it just returns an empty template, it does not display any data.

This is my template:

```
    <table id="search-results-primers-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Primer Name</th>
        <th>Primer Sequence</th>
        <th>Purchase Order</th>
        <th>Date Received</th>
        <th>Date Opened</th>
        <th>Date Discarded</th>
        <th>Freezer / Shelf</th>
        <th>Box / Position</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in result %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.primer_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.primer_seq }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.purchase_order }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.date_received }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.date_opened }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.date_discarded }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.stored_freezer }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.stored_box }}</td>
          </tr>      
        {% endfor %}
      </body>
    </table>
```

I have tried iterating as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803599/how-to-iterate-over-nested-dictionaries-in-django-templates), I have reorganized `result` using `dictionary = {i: d for i, d in enumerate(queryset)}`, and whatever else I could find but it just won't work, I know the problem has to be in the `result` that I am passing to render, or in `{% for item in result %}`, but I am so stuck with this, I have spent hours on this and still no results. I need a pair of fresh eyes to take a look and tell me what is it I'm doing wrong.

Comment: please which view does return the given template

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about that, the view for the shown template is `search_results_primers`.

Comment: remove the .values query expression from the Primer query object and try again

Comment: If I remove .values() from the query, it returns: `<QuerySet [<Primer: Ha-9-F>, <Primer: Ha-9-R>, <Primer: Ha-10-F>, <Primer: Ha-10R>, <Primer: Ha-33-F>, <Primer: Ha-33R>, <Primer: Ha-24-F>, <Primer: Ha-24R>, <Primer: Ha-4-F>, <Primer: Ha-4-R>, <Primer: Ha-3-F>, <Primer: Ha-3-R>, <Primer: Ha-31-F>, <Primer: Ha-31R>, <Primer: Ha-23-F>, , '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
` and that is not the result that I want. I need all rows that contain the value 'Ha' in the 'primer_name' field, not just the values from the 'primer_name' column.

Comment: please post `search_results_primers` view

Comment: It is posted, it is the last one of the 3 views that I posted.

Comment: @BrianObot, if I remove values() from the query, I get this error: ValueError at /search_results_primers/

The view lab_inventory.views.search_results_primers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the context, the queryset was passed in the keyword `query`, you need to use that same keyword in the template so:

```
{% for item in query %}
    ...
```

About this error:

> didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

This can happen in `search_results_primers` if `filter_by` is not 'primer_name', causing your view to return nothing. To fix it, make sure your view returns a response when `filter_by` is not `primer_name`.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked! I knew it had to be a small mistake, but I just couldn't find it!

And you are also right about the ValueError error, I hadn't added all the options just yet so it gave me that error, I added a simple else statement to just give it that option while in development and problem solved. Thanks again!!!